Unable to ping Hyper-V host from Ubuntu VM
I'm having a networking issue with my Ubuntu server VM.
My Ubuntu VM is able to ping everything EXCEPT my Windows Host.
I've tried disabling the firewall on both sides, assigning a static MAC address, configuring my netplan yaml file.
I'm not sure where to go from here.
I've attached pictures of the issue, Host Ip config results, Ubuntu Ip address results, and my netpplan yaml file.








Your Windows DNS settings don’t appear to be correct. They probably should be set to its hosts ip address or a shared DNS ip address. It also does it appear that all the machines are in the same subnet.

@Ramhound Thanks for the reply, I've updated the DNS server to both use my default gateway. The same issue still persists. The host and guest should be on the same subnet as they both use a 255.255.0.0 subnetmask.

Why does the "VirtIO" interface still have IP configuration? Is it not enslaved to the the "external switch"? Which IP have you been trying to ping?

@TomYan
I don't fully understand the question, but I'll tell you what I know.
I assigned static IPs to both ethernet adapters (host & guest).
Host IP: 192.168.10.1
Guest IP: 192.168.10.2
I'm trying the ping the host IP 192.168.10.1.
I've also uploaded images of the IPV4 settings for both the host and guest. As well as my External Switch settings on hyper-v.
Thank you for the reply.

When "Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter" is chosen as the "External network" of an external switch, you shouldn't assign any IP to the adapter. The "host ip" (192.168.10.1) should be assigned on the switch. But note that since this is an external switch, "the outside" would then need to access the Windows host with that IP as well (and it should be an IP within the subnet used by this "outside"). I have no idea why you would have 192.168.10.2 on a Windows configuration box, since you said the IP should be the guest IP, and for that it should appear only on configuration inside the VM.

Btw if there's no real reason for you to use 192.168.10.1, you can really just leave DHCP on the switch and access the host with 192.168.0.90.
